# Namespace issue

Tags: c#, namespaces

This is driving me crazy!  I'm trying to get to a namespace for a thrid party control called: HotDocs.Server.Session.

My namespaces start with CCE.HotDocs.IO and CCE.HotDocs.Test.

When I type "HotDocs." I get my namespaces that start with CCE.HotDocs ? WTF? I should be getting HotDocs.Server What am I missing?  I captured a couple of screen snippets to show what I mean... the second screen snippet is what is driving me crazy.

[image: Namespace Conflict]

[image: Namespace Conflict 2]

Comment: Type in `Session` and see if it suggests the namespace you are looking for.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: Include a screenshot of where your using statements are declared.  Try moving them inside the namespace declaration if you're declaring them outside of it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use global::HotDocs.

or try:

Create alias for one of them:
using myAlias = HotDocs.Server;

Comment: Using the alias allowed me to see the classes with the Server namespace.  Not sure why I get CCE. namespaces when I started typing the HotDocs namespace - this remains unexplained!  Intellisense looks like it's searching all namespaces that contain rather than start with HotDocs - but that does not explain why the Server namespace is not shown.  Very strange!